# Line graph for two set of data

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code it works well one set of data.
but my requirement is like user enter values like "loc1" means it picks corresponding "loc1" data from the two datasets.
**graph output is for only two lines (loc1 in dataset1 and loc1 in dataset2 )**
anyone have any suggestions for this .

is this below code is possible

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(7, 2), Cells(18, 2)),Range(Cells(7, 6), Cells(18, 6)
```

[image]

```
Sub alarmGraph()
    Dim ochart As Object, ochartObj As Object
    Dim countryRow As Integer, lastrow As Integer
    Set ochartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=ActiveCell.Left, Width:=650, Top:=ActiveCell.Top, Height:=450)
    Set ochart = ochartObj.Chart
    ochart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    ochart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Range("B2:E13")
    ochart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("A2:A13")
    ochart.Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
    ochart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Caption = "Year"
    ochart.Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True
    ochart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Caption = "Values"
End Sub
```

Comment: Use named ranges

Comment: Hi all ,is it possible to give code like below

Comment: ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(7, 2), Cells(18, 2)),Range(Cells(7, 6), Cells(18, 6))

Comment: Better add such question into your question, not add as comment.